# pythonic way to merge dictionaries where identical keys merged into a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to merge two dictionaries.

The dictionaries structure is identical, that is, the keys are the same and the corresponding types of the values are the same as well.

In case the type of a value is a list then the second list should extend the first list.

Elements of a dictionary may be a dictionary.

```
d1 = {"a":1, "b":[2], "c":{"d":3}}
d2 = {"a":5, "b":[6], "c":{"d":7}}
```

expected merged dictionary:

```
merge(d1,d2) = {"a":[1,5], "b":[2,6], "c":{"d":[3,7]}}
```

Doing this recursively is fairly simple, I wonder if there is something maybe like 'map' that does not require an explicit recursion.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Where are you stuck? And why don't you want to do it recursively?

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense to your input. Shouldn't that be `"b":[[2], [6]]"`?

Comment: @AdamSmith: I assume he's expecting to implicitly flatten lists, and to implicitly recurse (but not recursively!) into dicts.

Comment: If not, what's the merge for `[2,6]` and `[6,7]`?

Comment: Meanwhile, when you say "The dictionaries structure is identical", does that mean every dictionary will have the same structure as this example (`a`, `b` and `c` keys, with a `d` key inside the value of the `c` key), or just that each pair of dictionaries will have the same structure as each other?

Comment: yes, I expect flatten lists. the output for [2,6] [6,7] in my case should be [2,6,6,7]

Comment: And possibly more importantly, what's the merge for unlike types? where `d1['c'] == {"d":[3,7]}` and `d2['c'] == [1,2,3]` for instance?

Comment: in my case the structures are identical both in keys and leaves types

Comment: So are you going to answer any of my questions? You're obviously reading the comments, but I still have no idea whether every dict will have this structure, why you don't want to do it recursively, where you're stuck, or what you've tried, so I don't know how to help.

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid recursion in this situation? It seems like the obvious way to deal with the merging of the nested dictionaries. If you really want to you could probably use a stack of dictionaries to be merged, but it would be a bunch of extra work.

Comment: There is no one tool that is going to make this for you, you're mixing a lot of behaviors into this output. 

We're generating arrays for primitive literals, concatenating arrays, and zipping  dictionary key mappings and then seemingly applying the previous rules.

Individually, each of these actions is not particularly difficult and can be accomplished in a line or two, but you've created an state machine with many options here.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is the most natural way to solve this problem:

```
def merge_dicts(d1, d2):
    result = {}
    for k, v1 in d1.items():
        v2 = d2[k]
        if isinstance(v1, dict):
            result[k] = merge_dicts(v1, v2)
        elif isinstance(v1, (list, tuple)):
            result[k] = v1 + v2
        else:
            result[k] = [v1, v2]
    return result
```

This should work just fine for any sane data structure. To hit the recursion limit, your input would need to have nested dictionaries a thousand levels deep. If you have that kind of structure, the recursion limit is likely the least of your problems.

If just want to avoid recursion on principle (or you are learning how to convert recursive code to iterative code), you can get the same result by maintaining a list of dictionaries that need to be merged. The easiest way is probably by using a three-tuple of dictionaries `target, source1, source2` as a "job". As you process each job, you may add more jobs to the end of the list, to be merged later.

```
def merge_dicts_non_recursive(d1, d2):
    result = {}
    todo = [(result, d1, d2)] # start with one job to do
    for target, source1, source2 in todo: # unpack next job into variables
        for k, v1 in source1.items(): # mostly the same logic as the recursive version
            v2 = source2[k]
            if isinstance(v1, dict): # except for this case, where we don't recurse
                new_target = {}
                todo.append((new_target, v1, v2)) # add a new job to the list
                target[k] = new_target
            elif isinstance(v1, (list, tuple)):
                target[k] = v1 + v2
            else:
                target[k] = [v1, v2]
    return result
```

This code is a bit tricky as it adds new jobs to the `todo` list while iterating over it. Often, modifying an iterable while you are iterating over it is an error, but in this situation it does exactly what we want.